# Any C/C++ compiler which uses 8 bytes as the size of int data type on a 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, c, int, sizeof

are there any C/C++ compilers which use 8bytes as the size of int data type?

```
printf("Size of int = %d bytes",sizeof(int));
```

Here the output should be :-

```
Size of int = 8 bytes
```

Please name such a compiler 
Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with using a `long`?

Comment: It doesn't solely depend on compiler .

Comment: You can't guarantee the output of that `printf` when using the wrong format specifier. `size_t` requires `%zu`.

Comment: That is the ILP64 data model. It is used on the SPARC64 port of Solaris. This is not something that is usually set by the compiler, as ameyCU said.

Comment: If you care about integer width, use `<cstdint>` ie. `int64_t` vs `int32_t`; BTW, a C++ or C compiler could have `char` taking 32 bits and `sizeof(int)` being 1. IIRC some C implementation above [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) does that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the section on 64 bit data models in [the Wikipedia entry for 64 bit computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) you will see that there are two models where `int`s are 64 bits, `ILP64` and `SILP64`. An example given for ILP64 is HAL Computer Systems port of Solaris to SPARC64, and for SILP64 "Classic" [UNICOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNICOS). Obviously any compiler for either of these two systems would need to use 64 bit `int`s, although they are both somewhat obscure.

Most common 64 bit environments are `LP64` of course, where `int` is 32 bits.